# java web applications

Tags: html, css

I have a problem trying an excercise so I need help for this:

Index:

```
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>My first servlet page </h1>

</body>
```

Servlet:

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {
            /* TODO output your page here. You may use following sample code. */
        out.println("<!DOCTYPE html>");
        out.println("<html>");
        out.println("<head>");
        out.println("<title>Servlet primerservlet</title>");            
        out.println("</head>");
        out.println("<body>");
        out.println("<h1>" + request.getContextPath() + "</h1>");
        out.println("</body>");
        out.println("</html>");

    }
}
```

JSP:

```
       </form>      


    <h1>Server hour:  <%= new java.util.Date() %> </h1>

   <h3>Background color</h3>
  <select>

      <option value="">Select background color</option>
      <option value="1"> Blue</option>
      <option value="2">Red</option>
      <option value="3">green</option>
      <option value="4">pink</option>
 </select>

    <h3> Select font color</h3>
 <select>
          <option value="">Select an option</option>
          <option  value="1">blue</option>
          <option value="2">red</option>
          <option value="3">green</option>
          <option value="4">pink</option>
</select>
    <input type="Submit" value="Change">
```

So I want to change background color and text of server hour with select tag, pressing button "change" like this

Your help is very appreciated,

Comment: Aren't you using html form to submit ? Here you can do it with just one jsp, no need for extra servlets/jsp..

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
<input type="Submit" value="Change">
```

to

```
<input type="button" value="Change" onClick="changeColor();">
```

Change

`<select>` to `<select id="myID">`

Add to javascript code

```
function changeColor()
{

    $('h1').css({'color' :  $("#myId option:selected").html()});
    $('h3').css('background-color',  $("#myId option:selected").html());
}
```

Comment: it no worked :/, there not any form, that I call submit on servlet? somthing like out.println("<input>" + request.getParameter(Change) + "</input>"); ?

Comment: @GerardoQuintana, Change submit to button & remember to include the jquery file.

Answer (score 0):

i hope you are looking for this

```js
$( "#select-background" ).change(function() {
     $("h1").css('background-color',this.options[this.value].text);
});
$( "#select-color" ).change(function() {
     $("h1").css('color',this.options[this.value].text);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Server hour</h1>
<h3>Background color</h3>
 <select id="select-background">
          <option value="">Select an option</option>
          <option  value="1">blue</option>
          <option value="2">red</option>
          <option value="3">green</option>
          <option value="4">pink</option>
</select>
<h3> Select font color</h3>
 <select id="select-color">
          <option value="">Select an option</option>
          <option  value="1">blue</option>
          <option value="2">red</option>
          <option value="3">green</option>
          <option value="4">pink</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I think the idea is for them to learn case switching on the Java servlet side not just change it through local browser javascript. Java programming class =) kid getting you to do their homework for them lol

Answer (score 0):

This solution is just with one jsp:

```
<form method="post">
  <h1 style="color:${param.color};background:${param.bg};">Server Time:<%=new java.util.Date()%></h1>
  <h3>Background color</h3>
  <select name="bg">
    <option value="">Select background color</option>
    <option>Blue</option>
    <option>Red</option>
    <option>green</option>
    <option>pink</option>
  </select>

  <h3>Select font color</h3>
  <select name="color">
    <option value="">Select an option</option>
    <option>blue</option>
    <option>red</option>
    <option>green</option>
    <option>pink</option>
  </select>
  <input type="Submit" value="Change" />
</form>
```

Comment: Bcoz, its not within the form tag, BTW did my solution worked for you?